# Unable to load urls in iframe on using ajax call

Tags: domain, ruby-on-rails, haproxy

My application is deployed under haproxy server with domain name say fireapp.com, server1 and server2 are two servers below. Haproxy is configured to handle all requests under /live/ url format from server2.

`Server2 contains live apps in format /live/app1, /live/app2`. So

```
http://fireapp.com/live/app1 and fireapp.com/live/app2 are served from server2.
```

Server1 is the web application in which home page loads an iframe. Iframe is using urls like

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://fireapp.com/live/app1" width="850px" height="900px" ></iframe>
```

When the page loads it throws error message, firebug says 404:network error for `http://fireapp.com/live/app1`. While the app is available on

```
 http://fireapp.com/live/app1 or http://server-2/live/app1.
```

Using

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="http://server-2/live/app1" width="850px" height="900px" ></iframe>
```

works but it comes under cross domain issue which i'm trying to avoid. I also tried providing only relative path but it fails on first load again.

```
<iframe id="iframe" src="/live/app1" width="850px" height="900px" ></iframe>
```

Just after page load if i try to update the src of iframe using the same previous url from console, it loads up the page.

Update:
Haproxy file.

```
  global
    log 127.0.0.1 local0 notice
    maxconn 2000
    user haproxy
    group haproxy

defaults
    log     global
    mode    http
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect  50000
    timeout client  100000
    timeout server  100000

frontend http
 bind :80
 acl example path_reg -i ^/ey-\b
 #acl url_static       path_end       -i .jpg .gif .png .css .js
 acl url_stats path_beg /haproxy-stats


  use_backend  be_stats if url_stats
  use_backend static    if example

default_backend       app

backend be_stats
 stats uri /haproxy-stats

backend static
 balance     roundrobin
 server host1 10.0.0.234:80 check
 #server      static 10.211.***.***:80 check

backend app
 balance     roundrobin
 server  host1 10.0.0.***:80 check
```

Comment: Can you share the complete `frontend/backend/listen` config for haproxy? I'm especially interested wether you are using `httpclose`.

Comment: @FelixFrank please check with the update, i have updated with haproxy file

Answer (score 0):

Try setting `option httpclose` or better `option http-server-close`.

In your configuration, haproxy will allow the browser to request the iframe content through the same keepalive connection as the original request, and the ACL that is supposed to make sure that the correct server is used will not have a chance to take effect.

Whenever you use ACLs and/or request manipulation options, you need to make sure that the appservers are not allowed to keep client connections open.